# How to prevent texstudio from completing "arrowvert"

Tags: diagrams, texstudio

I'm drawing commutative diagrams using tikz-cd, using texstudio. However, every time I write "\arrow[", texstudio replaces that with "\arrowvert[".

This is really annoying. Can I change that behaviour without turning off the replacement mechanism altogether?

Comment: Great question... So annoying, indeed. Please report that to the maintainers of TeXstudio as they have to add this for you. In the meantime: Use `\ar[]` which is the same or press Esc after typing `\arrow[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can deactivate the completion at `Options -> Completion -> Complete selected text when non-word character is pressed`. (Note: You need to have advanced options enabled in the dialog to this setting).
2. You can create a completion file for tikz-cd and add `\arrow` to it. See [Why does a command not show up in the completion](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion) and the links therein. If you do so, we would be happy if you would send us the file. Then we can include it in future releases of TXS.

Comment: It's been a while since this question and answer were posted, but I see there is still a lack of a "standard" cwl file for tikz-cd. I found [this old basic file](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1321/?limit=25) by Fernando Muro to be of help.

Comment: This files is part of TeXstudio 2.12.8.